# Write raw SQL for PostGIS

Tags: sql, spatial, postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to input some data into a PostgreSQL 8.4 database with a PostGIS template. I'm unable to `UPDATE` polygons:

```
> UPDATE my_table SET coords = POINT(1, 1)
UPDATE 0 1

> UPDATE my_table SET box = POLYGON(((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1)))
ERROR:  function polygon(record) does not exist

> UPDATE my_table SET box = POLYGON((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1))
ERROR:  function polygon(record, record, record, record) does not exist

> UPDATE my_table SET box = POLYGON(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1)
ERROR:  function polygon(numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric) does not exist

> UPDATE my_table SET box = ((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1))
ERROR:  column "box" is of type polygon but expression is of type record
```

How do I insert a polygon? Note that the data already exists in the table, with `NULL` fields in place of the spatial data. I need to `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You may find more expert answers to GIS related questions in the dedicated site http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @amercader thanks! I didn't know about `gis`.meta.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Geometry constructors](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id2575932) to load new geometries in your table, specifically the [St_GeomFromText](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) function:

```
UPDATE my_table SET box = ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((1 1), (2 3), (3 3), (1 1))');
```

The geometry is defined in the WKT ([Well-Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)) format.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE my_table SET box = '((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 1))'::polygon;
```

To my knowledge, *most* geometric types in general need the quotes.